# Ext.NET Combobox set default value

Tags: c#, ext.net

Below is markup of my combobox

```
X.ComboBox()
 .ID("cmbStatus")
 .DisplayField("Value")
 .ValueField("Key")
 .Items(new ListItem ("C", "C"), 
 new ListItem ("H", "H"), 
 new ListItem("C & H","C&H"),
 new ListItem ("ALL","ALL")
 )
.Listeners(l => { l.Select.Handler = "StatusChange(this)"; })
.FieldLabel(PR.Resources.IP.IP.Status)
```

how do i set the default any one value selected in combobox?

i tried setting,
`.Select(0)` and `.SelectedItems(new ListItem("C"))`

with the help of 2nd approach above i'm able to set default selected but it's causing me problem in function `StatusChange(this)`..

in `StatusChange(this)` function i'm hiding another control based on selected value in `cmbStatus`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
   .Value("C&H")
```

So, using your example, to have the third item selected by default:

```cs
X.ComboBox()
   .ID("cmbStatus")
   .DisplayField("Value")
   .ValueField("Key")
   .Items(
      new ListItem ("C", "C"), 
      new ListItem ("H", "H"), 
      new ListItem("C & H","C&H"),
      new ListItem ("ALL","ALL")
   )
   .Value("C&H")
   .Listeners(l => { l.Select.Handler = "StatusChange(this)"; })
   .FieldLabel(PR.Resources.IP.IP.Status)
```